# Want to take a radio and checkbox value from one form to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have values from one form that need to be transferred to another.

```
var manager = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').val();
```

I'm capturing the value with this. and trying to send it to this.

```
$('input[type=checkbox]:checked').val(manager);
```

but I don't know what to put into the next set of jquery to transfer it over.

`.val()` works for strings/numbers but not checkboxes or radio buttons which I am trying to do.

Please advice.

Comment: Please include your html and your jquery code

Comment: The question is not clear on what is the problem. Add more detail and obviously, HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try jQuery `prop()` function to transfer the state of one checkbox to another.

Also use correct selectors. `$('input[type=checkbox]:checked')` will only select CHECKED checkboxes.

see this fiddle for an example: https://jsfiddle.net/iPirat/p5f07br4/

in this fiddle, the checkbox in the first form is selected similarly to what you did. 
the checkbox insecond form is selected using an ID.